# Problemas con variable tipo vector - USANDO R

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente problema y es que esta sentencia

```
summary(mydata3$AugmentFact)
```

No consigo hacerla funcionar por que el objeto `mydata3` no existe,vale,creo el objeto `mydata3` pero al parecer es de tipo vector,pues bien creo esa variable de tipo vector pero cuando ejecuto la sentencia me da el siguiente error..

> [36] ERROR: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Y la verdad no se como crear el vector ya que pienso que lo creo bien pero no me va.

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en la documentación del operador "$" dice que solo es aplicable para objetos recursivos (para ver esto escribís en la consola: `?"$"`).

Un vector no es un objeto recursivo, así que tienes que usar corchetes para seleccionar los atributos o elementos que necesites.

```
>is.recursive(mydata3)
[1] FALSE
```

Así que podrías intentar con el siguiente comando:

```
summary(mydata3['AugmentFact'])
```